# Find matching brackets in output?

Tags: front-end

Outputs are often lengthy and contain many nested brackets. Is there a way to identify the matching open bracket if I select a closing bracket in an output expression? (*Mathematica* 7)

Comment: Later versions of *Mathematica* highlight matching bracket pairs. Some previous versions had "Check Balance" in right click menu for square brackets.

Comment: `Ctrl+.` will expand selection so in your case up to the matching bracket.

Comment: That works! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Some other possibilities:

1. Triple click
2. Use Check Balance from the edit menu (Shift Command B on a Mac).

Option 2 is useful when you are editing `InputForm`, e.g.:

ListPlot[Range[5]] //InputForm

where both triple click and Ctrl-. don't work.